# Why are these quotations ending the PHP query in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: php, mysql, sublimetext2

I'm trying to write some queries to responsively manipulate MySQL data, but Sublime Text 2 is showing that the query is ending before I want it to. Check out below:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`) VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."','".md5(md5($_POST['email'].$_POST['password']))."')";
```

The comma and closing parenthesis should be white.

And again, here is the same issue:

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email`='".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['login-email'])."' AND `password`='".md5(md5($_POST['login-email'].$_POST['login-password']))."'";
```

I'm having an awfully difficult time figuring out how to write this code so that I can make sure it's not a bug in my script.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am afraid simply pasting the text here is not very helpful to diagnose the issue, especially for those who do not have sublime text. Perhaps a screenshot might be appropriate here ?

Comment: Aside from the slightly dubious hashing of passwords, your code looks fine. Maybe it's just a bug in Sublime? Stackoverflow seems to highlight the code properly (albeit in PHP code style and not mixed PHP/SQL).

Comment: Use prepared statements and you won't have to break up your query when passing in a dynamic parameter / variable:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: The syntax highlighting looks fine in my sublime editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a limitation of Sublime's syntax highlighting.  Notice that in both queries, SQL syntax highlighting ends immediately after first instance of string concatenation.  If you want more thorough highlighting for your SQL statements, you may want to consider using prepared statements.  Example:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param($_POST['email'], md5(md5($_POST['email'].$_POST['password'])));
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

This approach will also negate the need of manually escaping your strings.

- Simple examples: http://mattbango.com/notebook/code/prepared-statements-in-php-and-mysqli/
- Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php
- Full Mysqli docs: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Alternatively, you may want to consider using string interpolation instead of concatentation.  This does not seem to intefere with SQL syntax highlighting either.

Answer (score 0):

There is no bug in your script. The highlighting looks perfectly fine in my Sublime Text.
You are concatenating the text several times, and the highlighting of code outside the double quotes `"` will definitely be different from that inside the double quotes. However, to write the code in a better way, you may consider following:

```
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email']);
$pass = md5(md5($_POST['email'].$_POST['password']));
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`) VALUES('$email','$pass')";
```

And similarly for the `select` command.